# Formatting Issue in csv file while trying to scrape the following website

Tags: python, selenium, csv, web-scraping, export-to-csv

**I am trying to scrape a website to get the title and prices but once the data is extracted and saved on the csv file the prices column formatting get disturbed and is not properly displayed in the column e.g $8,900 become $8 in one column and 900 is shifted to next column.**

```
from selenium import webdriver
import time

max_pages = 1
driver = webdriver.Chrome()
with open('autotrader.csv', 'w') as f:
    f.write("Title,Price \n")

for i in range(1, max_pages + 1):
    url =  "https://www.autotrader.co.uk/car-search?advertClassification=standard&postcode=WC2N%205DU&onesearchad=Used&onesearchad=Nearly%20New&onesearchad=New&advertising-location=at_cars&is-quick-search=TRUE&include-delivery-option=on&page=" + str(max_pages)

driver.get(url)
title = driver.find_elements_by_xpath('//h3[@class="product-card-details__title"]')
price =driver.find_elements_by_xpath('//div[@class="product-card-pricing__price"]')
page_items = len(title)
with open('autotrader.csv', 'a') as f:
    for i in range(page_items):
        f.write(title[i].text + "," + price[i].text + "\n")
driver.close()
```

Comment: CSV means comma seperated values. Use the `|` (pipe) char to delimit your columns, i.e. `f.write(title[i].text + "|" + price[i].text + "\n")`. Good luck.

Comment: you can also just quote all entries

Comment: @pcalkins i don't understand

Comment: @shellter it didn't solve my problem unfortunately, half of the  price is now attached with the title

Comment: if you just quote all your entries then you can include the separator if it is a part of the data...  (use double-quotes... and then be sure to filter out any incoming double-quotes... though I think you'd get "&quot;" instead...)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `csv.writer` and it will properly quote fields with delimiter characters in them:

```
import csv

# ... code to fetch titles and prices ...

with open('autotrader.csv', 'w', newline='') as f:
    w = csv.writer(f)
    w.writerow(['Title','Price'])
    for t,p in zip(title,price):
        w.writerow([t.text,p.text])
```